# How do you add captions to individual tile sources in an array with openseadragon?

Tags: javascript, openseadragon

I have openseadragon working well to load tilesources from an array. The tile sources are pulled from a mysql table and look like:

```
$tilesources = "/images/20190726075000_100/a20190726075000_100.dzi","/images/20190726075000_100/a20190726075000_100.dzi"
```

The javascript:

```
(function() {
    const viewer = new OpenSeadragon.Viewer({
        id: "openseadragon-<?php echo $imgid; ?>",
        prefixUrl: '/assets/openseadragon/images/', // prefix for image control buttons folder
        tileSources: [ <?php echo "$tilesources"; ?> ],
        controlsFadeDelay: 60000,
        navigationControlAnchor: OpenSeadragon.ControlAnchor.BOTTOM_RIGHT, // controls position 
        navigationControlAnchor: OpenSeadragon.ControlAnchor.TOP_RIGHT, // controls position 
        homeFillsViewer: true,
        defaultZoomLevel: 1.2,
        zoomPerClick: 1.5,          
        sequenceMode: true,
        showFullPageControl: true, // works
      });
    })();
```

I wrapped it up so that it displays in fancybox. With fancybox I added a basic caption using data-caption=''. This gives the a general common caption to the viewer/viewport.

The problem is that each individual tile source has it's own caption. I don't see an option in openseadragon to add captions each tile.

I am wondering if there is a way to add a callback (whatever you might call it) to dynamically update the fancybox title as you navigate through the tiles?

Answer (score 0):

There's an event for when the user navigates to a new image in sequence mode. You could do something like so:

```
var captions = [ <?php echo "$captions"; ?> ];

viewer.addHandler('page', function(event) {
  var caption = captions[event.page];
  // Update the caption element with the caption
});
```